# Incorrect scaling in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I made an assistant app for me only, so I only need it to work perfectly on one device. (OnePlus 8 Pro)

this is what my app should look like [screenshot from 1440x3168 AVD]:

[image: how it should be displayed]

but this is what it looks like on my phone [also 1440x3168]:
[image: how it actually is displayed]

here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="480dp"
    android:layout_height="832dp"
    android:scrollbarSize="12dip"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/viewConstraint"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/viewConstraint">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/command_body"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bubble"
            android:fontFamily="@font/productsans"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:maxWidth="360dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
            android:paddingVertical="4dp"
            android:text="asdf"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewConstraint"
    android:layout_width="480dp"
    android:layout_height="832dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/RectangleBottom"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/RectangleTop">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/RectangleBottom"
    android:layout_width="480dp"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:src="@drawable/rectangle_bottom"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"> </ImageView>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/commandID"
    android:layout_width="373dp"
    android:layout_height="92dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="@font/productsans_bold"
    android:hint="@string/command"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textShortMessage"
    android:maxLength="128"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/textColor"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textColorLink="@color/textColor"
    android:textSize="48sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.149"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/RectangleBottom" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/SendButton"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
    android:onClick="getCommand"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/commandID"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/RectangleBottom"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle_send" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actionsText"
    android:layout_width="192dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/productsans_bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="64sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/RectangleTop"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/RectangleTop"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

what could the issue be? It works fine in the AVD, but it doesn't work on the device it's meant for. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You specified font size using `sp` units which can vary depending on your **user** setting for font size (which apparently you have set differently on your device than on emulator). So either make it smaller (i.e `16sp`) or use `dp` instead if that's ok.